# Doob's maximal inequality with stopping time

Tags: probability, inequality

I have been searching for a version of Doob's maximal inequality with stopping time insides the time index, i.e. given $\Lambda_n$ is a positive sub-martingale and N is a stopping time is there any inequality like
$P(\max_{0\leq n\leq N}\Lambda_n > B) \leq \frac{E[\Lambda_N]}{B}$?

Comment: What if you apply Doob's inequality to the submartingale stopped at time $T$, on the time segment $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, and then let $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins : thank you for your comment and your nice idea! I believe for that to be true we need the assumption of stopping time $T$ to be bounded almost surely. Since otherwise there may be sequences of $\omega_i \in \Omega$ such that $T(\omega_i)$ goes to infinity itself. Here we at most have the assumption that stopping time is finite. Do you think we can somehow overcome the assumption of being bounded?

Comment: Good point.  Here's an example: $\Lambda_n$ is simple symmetric random walk on the integers started at $1$, and $N=\min\{n:\Lambda_n=0\}$. Then $P(\max_{0\le n\le N}\Lambda_n>B)>0$ for all $B>0$, but $E(\Lambda_N)=0$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: Oh I see! a true counterexample.